# JavaScript accessing variables declared in calling function

Tags: javascript, scope

It's hard to explain my question, so I'm posting some code.

```
function caller(func) {
    function printMessage(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }

    func();
}

function callee() {
    printMessage('hello world');
}

caller(callee);
```

I want to access printMessage from callee, but as it currently stands, this throws a ReferenceError. I'd like to avoid declaring printMessage globally, if possible.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?  An object like `console`, that wraps the implementation?

Comment: The caller function will be part of a library, with the callee function being written by a user. printMessage is part of the API, so users need to be able to call it in their code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eval seems to achieve this rather elegantly.

```
function caller(func) {
    function printMessage(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }

    eval('(' + func.toString() + ')();');
}

function callee() {
    printMessage('hello world');
}

caller(callee);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the function you want to use inside of `callee` as a parameter to `callee`; so long as the caller has access, then `callee` doesn't care where it was defined:

```
function caller(func) {
    ....
    func(printMessage);
}

function callee( func ) {
    func("hello world");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do would be to have 'caller' call the function passed into it, and print the returned value.

```
function caller(func) {
  function printMessage(message) {
    console.log(message);
  }
  printMessage(func());
}
function callee() {
  return 'hello world';
}
function callee2() {
  return 'hello world 2';
}
caller(callee);
caller(callee2);
```

Edit

After reading your comments on question, this may be better suited to an OO approach e.g:

```
//--- Base 'libary' caller ---//
var caller = function() {

}
//--- Add out printMessage function to our base libary ---//
caller.prototype.printMessage = function(message){
    console.log(message);
}

//--- Users 'libary' callee ---//
var callee = function() {
    caller.call(this);
    //--- Our users libary has a printing function ---//
    this.print = function ( message ) {
        this.printMessage("callee > " + message);
    }
}
callee.prototype = Object.create(caller.prototype); // Set callee's prototype to caller's prototype
callee.prototype.constructor = callee; // Set constructor back to callee

//--- Using the users libary ---//
var userLibary = new callee();
userLibary.print("hello world"); // 'callee > hello world'
//--- The original libary's print method is still accessible ---//
userLibary.printMessage("hello world"); // 'hello world'
```

Comment: This doesn't allow for printMessage to be accessed from callee.

Comment: Hi there, I have just updated the code to have an OOP approach, this allows the users library to use & extend the original library's function. ( A good read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript )

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't. The nested `printMessage` is limited to `caller` scope only.

You can access the `caller` constructor function by its `calee.caller` prototype but it's "locked" under caller's scope only..

Just for info:

```
function caller(func) {
    function printMessage(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }

    func();
}

function callee() {
    //you can access the caller's constructor from prototype..
    var callerFunc = arguments.callee.caller.prototype;
    console.log(callerFunc);
    //you can get the actual code
    var code = arguments.callee.caller.toString();
    console.log(code);

    //but you can't invoke the nested function which is under
    //caller scope only...will throw ReferenceError
    printMessage('hello world');
}

caller(callee);
```

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ufxnoaL1/

Also, note that `arguments.callee` will not be supported and should [not be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee)

> Warning: The 5th edition of ECMAScript (ES5) forbids use of
>   arguments.callee() in strict mode. Avoid using arguments.callee() by
>   either giving function expressions a name or use a function
>   declaration where a function must call itself.